# Python - Can I import specific classes when importing all from a package

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a package set up with a tree structure like

```
pkg\  
    __init__.py  
    module1.py  
        Class11  
        Class12  
    module2.py  
        Class21  
        function21
```

I want specific classes and functions to be in the global namespace such that when I start my script with

```
from pkg import *
```

I will be able to directly use, say, Class11, Class12, and function21. Is this possible? The motivation behind it is to allow for quick and light usages in small scripts or interactive mode. It's implicitly known that with longer scripts one would not use import all and traverse the package structure properly.

EDIT: I could import Class11, Class12, and function21 in pkg's `__init__.py`, but in this way, when I do the regular `import pkg` I will still be able to access Class11 by `pkg.Class11` instead of the proper `pkg.module1.Class11`. Preferably I want `pkg.module1.Class11` to be the only way if I'm not doing `import *`.

Comment: Why do you want `pkg.module1.Class1` to be the _only_ way? It can be the only _documented_ way, the way you show in your online help and sample code and so on, but generally, in Python, you don't try to prevent people from doing it wrong unless it's an "attractive nuisance". That's what the "consenting adults" clause means-you can work around most restrictions in Python very easily if you really need to, but as long as it's clear that you're doing so and therefore entering murky territory that's fine.

Comment: Remember that the Zen doesn't say "there should be one and only one way to do it", just "one and only one *obvious* way".

Comment: @abarnert I do understand that you don't generally completely restrict the user's control in Python, but I was wondering if there was some convention for the scenario I described, such as the underscore naming scheme for private variables. Although, I do like what you said. Only documenting it a certain way is as good of a rough guide as any. I might just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The `*` means "everything".<sup>*</sup> If you don't want everything, but instead want a specific list of names, just use those names:

```
from pkg import Class11, Class21, function21
```

---

Of course this assumes that `pkg` already imports those names from its submodules. But if that weren't true, your `*` import wouldn't work either.

If that isn't true, but you want to know how to make it true, you just do something similar in `pkg/__init__.py`:

```
from .module1 import Class11, Class12
from .module2 import Class21, function21
```

Or, maybe:

```
from .module1 import __all__ as _all1
from .module2 import __all__ as _all2
from .module1 import *
from .module2 import *

__all__ = _all1 + _all2
```

---

<sub>* Well, not quite "everything". If there's an `__all__`, it means "every name in `__all__`"; if not, it means "every name that doesn't start with `_`". But close enough for our purposes.</sub>

Comment: If I understand `__init__` correctly, doing this will also allows you to do `pkg.Class11` when you start with `import pkg`, is that right? Is there a way to force (or pythonistically guide) the user to write `pkg.module1.Class11` when they are not using `from pkg import *`?

Comment: @Remy there is a very ugly hack that I can think of that might work, but generally you should assume that `from pkg import *` is indistinguishable from `from pkg import Class11, Class12, Class21`; and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm somewhat curious what your ugly hack is, because the first thing I thought of (well, the second after walking the frame from `import`, which is _beyond_ very ugly...) didn't work. But not curious enough to want to get in the way of the good point you made in the second half. :)

Comment: Put a custom object in `sys.modules[]` that would have `__all__` as a property; accessing that would then trigger the import of stuff from submodules; I don't know if it would work properly though, and not too interested in trying :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, that's much simpler than the guess I came up with while you were writing that of subclassing `ModuleType` and overriding `__getattr__`, but I think yours will work of mine does anyway. Anyway, agreed, not worth the effort to build and test either version.

Comment: I believe only `from mod import *` would access `__all__`, so it could be enough to have `from mod import *` trigger the module being filled with all the stuff in `@property def __all__()`

Comment: @Remy Having a complex package "fake" being a flat module for the "simple" use cases is pretty common in both the stdlib and some popular PyPI projects. (See the other answer that uses Flask as an example.) And "simple" use cases include doing "import *" in the interactive interpreter, and I think it might be surprising if you made them different.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah, but a `@property` has to be on the class, not the instance. That's basically why I was thinking of subclassing `ModuleType` in the first place (although I was going to build a custom descriptor; your version is again simpler without losing anything...).

Comment: Ah btw you have an unnecessary import for the `__all__`; `__all__ = module1.__all__ + module2.__all__` would work **iff** they are direct submodules

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're right, I over-generalized it; you rarely need to do it the complicated way in real projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See what Flask did [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/__init__.py]):

Basically, you can import the functions and classes in `__init__.py` like this:

```
from .app import Flask, Request, Response
from .config import Config
```

Now we can do:

```
from Flask import Flask ,Request
```

Answer (score -1):

Set up your `__init__.py` like this:

```
from .module1 import Class11, Class12
from .module2 import Class21, function21
```